# Disable extra (page?) numbers showing up in kobo

Tags: epub, kobo

Hello I am packaging an epub book and I'm seeing numbers that aren't in my source on kobo. It looks like they're being added by kobo. They don't show up on Calibre or apple books.app or on kindle.

Here's a photo:

[image]

In the red circled area there's the number 6 which isn't in my xhmtl source. The page number that kobo is showing is page 6 at the bottom. So I believe that it's meant to represent the current page number.

The xhtml for that section is:

```
<section class="content" id="chapter-2" epub:type="chapter" >
<h2 class="title"><span class="chapter-number">Chapter 2:</span>
Intro</h2>
 # ...
</section>
```

My guess is that kobo is doing something special with `epub:type="chapter"` or `class="title"` but it's not something I intentionally specified in the CSS and I can't figure out how to turn it off.

Here's another page with a number also circled in red:

[image]

In this case, the num isn't associated with any special content:

```
<p>Another way to think of these higher-level docs is that they’re
more focused on tasks than on low-level plumbing. Because of this
task-based focus, you can also have different guides that speak to
diverse communities.</p>
```

Any idea why these are showing up or how to disable them in CSS or some other way?

Answer (score 2):

The page numbers you're seeing are inserted by the (Adobe) RMSDK used to render epubs on Kobo. You can go to Settings and under "Page Appearance", uncheck "Show Adobe EPUB page numbers".

You can also convert your epub to a kepub, which does not insert these page numbers.

Comment: Thank you! What’s your preferred way to generate a keypub?

Comment: The simplest way is to rename your file from filename.epub to filename.kepub.epub, but that will not enable all of the kepub features. You can also use the [Kepub Output plugin](https://plugins.calibre-ebook.com) or [Kepubify](https://github.com/joseluiscd/calibre-kepubify) in Calibre.